# Is it good practice to create index on all columns used in WHERE clause

Tags: postgresql, indexing, query-optimization, cpu-usage, timescaledb

The table stores time-series data and contains approx 15 columns.
I want to optimize the `SELECT` query which has filters on 3 columns

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_1
WHERE COL_1 = ? 
  AND COL_2 = ? 
  AND COL_3 = ?
```

There are 2 indexes created on `COL_1` and `COL_2` but not on `COL_3`. DB CPU is spiking to **100%** when RPS (Request per Second) is around 1K.

**DB Config is**

1. 8 CPUs
2. 16 GB RAM
3. 250 GB Storage

Is query processing more as there is no indexing on `COL_3`? Is it a good practice to create an index on each column used in the `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 10):

> Is it good practice to create index on all columns used in WHERE clause?

It is **not** good practice to create single-column indexes on all columns mentioned in WHERE clauses.  Those indexes don't help your queries much, and they cost time and IO when you do INSERT and UPDATE operations.

It **is** good practice to create [multicolumn indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/indexes-multicolumn.html) that match the WHERE clauses of your high-volume queries.

Your sample query

```sql
SELECT * FROM TABLE_1
WHERE COL_1 = ? 
  AND COL_2 = ? 
  AND COL_3 = ?
```

will benefit from a BTREE index on `(COL_1, COL_2, COL_3)`. postgresql can random-access the index to the first row in your table that matches your WHERE clause, then retrieve the rows by scanning the index.

If your query were

```sql
SELECT * FROM TABLE_1
WHERE COL_1 = ? 
  AND COL_TIME >= ? 
  AND COL_3 = ?
```

you would want an index on `(COL_1, COL_3, COL_TIME)`. Again, postgresql can random-access the index to the first eligible row, then scan the index sequentially until it gets to the last eligible row.  Put the equality-match columns first in the index, then the range match (`COL_TIME >= ?`) column.

Design your indexes to match

1. your database requirements for primary keys and other constraints.
2. your high-volume queries.

Just putting single-column indexes on many columns is a n00b mistake. Ask me how I know this sometime. ;-)

Indexing can seem arcane when you first start working with it. Marcus Winand's book https://use-the-index-luke.com/ is a good place to start learning.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I tried creating a multi-column index and ran the `explain analyse` on the same query, the result showed it wasn't using the multi-column index hence I created a separate index on each column. But, I don't remember the exact sequence I gave while creating the multi-column index. I might have messed with the sequence then.

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention that `COL_3` is actually enum and can have one value out of 10. Should I go-ahead to create an index on that column.

Comment: Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info) then ask another question about the particular query.

Comment: There is a lot of good in what you say, but sometimes few single-column indexes are better than many specialized multi-column indexes, particularly if you have to support many different `WHERE` conditions. PostgreSQL can combine scans on several indexes ("BitmapAnd" and "BitmapOr").

Comment: For your COL_3 that is an enum, you should place it into the INCLUDE clause of the index not into the key one.

Answer (score 0):

Indexing a table façing a query is not so easy that @OJones speaks... Because the WHERE clause is not the only SQL clause concerned in indexing the table... !

In fact all clauses of the query that are relative to the table you want to speed with indexes, must be analyzed.

As an example, the fact that you use a:

```
SELECT *
```

...into your query, does not help to be fast enough with an index containing only the columns used in the where clause. Very often, this index will not be used because to report all the values for all columns of the table (due to the SELECT *) the optimizer ("planer" as they say in PG) needs to do a seek into the index, and then do another access into the table to catch all columns that are not in the index definition...

Now you have the choice to create an index with all the columns of the table (and in this case the use of recently added INCLUDE clause like MS SQL Server does since 15 years, will help you to have a not too big index), or to reduce the returned columns listed in the SELECT clause and create a covering index...

A covering index is one that does not needs to access twice the table because it contains all the required columns of the query

In a french paper that you can read at :

[Que faut-il indexer ?](https://sqlpro.developpez.com/cours/quoi-indexer/#LIX)

I classify indexes with a "star" quotation:

- 1 star is an index that just cover the WHERE clause of a SELECT
- 2 stars is an index that cover WHERE and SELECT clause
- 3 stars is an index that cover WHERE, SELECT and ORDER BY clause
- 4 stars is an index that cover WHERE, SELECT, ORDER BY and GROUP BY clause

Answer (score 0):

Although indexing columns used in the WHERE clauses will improve query performance, it is not always necessary or beneficial to create a index on every column involved. When deciding whether to index columns in a WHERE clauses, we should consider the following factors like Query frequency, Data modifications & also Index maintenance.

I can say that it will be beneficial to index columns using in WHERE clauses, it is important to carefully consider each scenario and weigh the benefits against the costs of the index maintenance, storage & impact on the data modification operations. Finally, examine the specific requirement & feature of your application & database to make informed decisions about which columns to index.

In your scenario, since you are already experiencing high CPU usage & you have a filter on `COL_3`, it might be beneficial to create an index on `COL_3` as well.